# Do the Astral Suits from the Aegis ability have weight that affects encumbrance, armor check penalties, and speed penalties?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, armor, weight, aegis

Does the armor created by the [Aegis](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/) ability [Astral Suits](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/astral-suits) have weight that contributes to encumbrance, along with armor check penalties and speed penalties, like normal armor?

Answer (score 7):

### It seems that an astral suit that's like armor is *identical* to that armor in all ways—armor check penalty, speed reduction, weight, and more

On [Astral Suits](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/astral-suits) on Astral Suit Types on **Astral Armor**, in part, says

> When formed into astral armor, an astral suit resembles [masterwork](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipmenT/armor/#TOC-Masterwork-Armor) [chainmail](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/chainmail/) and is treated as such for all mechanical purposes.

And **Astral Juggernaut**, in part, says

> When formed into astral juggernaut, an astral suit resembles [masterwork](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipmenT/armor/#TOC-Masterwork-Armor) [half-plate](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/half-plate/) and is treated as such for all mechanical purposes.

The phrase *all mechanical purposes* strongly implies to this reader that these astral suits are just like the armors they emulate, including the emulated armor's weight, armor check penalty, speed reduction, and arcane spell failure chance.

The only additional indicator that I can find that backs up this reading is the 1-point Customization **Flexible Suit** that says

> The aegis’s armor check penalty is reduced by 1 (to a minimum of 0). The aegis may also sleep in his astral suit without becoming fatigued, if he was not already able to do so (such as if in astral skin form).

On [Armor Check Penalty](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipmenT/armor/#TOC-Armor-Check-Penalty), in part, says

> A character who sleeps in medium or heavy armor is automatically fatigued the next day.

This customization again strong implies that the astral armor and astral juggernaut effects are just like the armors they emulate unless exceptions are made, even down to details that some folks might otherwise overlook.

Comment: I edited to move your quotes into markdowns; I feel that it helps legibility.

Comment: @Ifusaso My old-school academic writing professors would cringe at formatting differently quotations of less than 4 lines long, but I'll accept that change for legibility. However, I just can't accept a verb introducing a quotation ***with a colon.*** With all due respect, kind sir, I cannot allow *that* to stand. [adjusts monocle; straightens top hat]

Comment: Hmmm... yes, quite. Good show.